# Skipping a Maven module that's already been published to Maven Central

Tags: maven, pom.xml, parent-pom

Let's say I have an aggregate Maven project. `com.example:foo:1.0.0` is the aggregate parent POM, and it contains the child project `com.example:bar:2.0.0`. I publish them both to Maven Central using the `nexus-staging-maven-plugin`. Note that I do *not* use dependency management in the parent POM for the version of `com.example:bar:2.0.0`, even though it is a child project. That is, the two versions are not tied together.

I also use `com.example:foo:1.0.0` as the parent POM in other projects, so I would prefer that its coordinates don't change unnecessarily (e.g. be published multiple times with different coordinates, even if the contents have not changed).

It turns out that `com.example:bar:2.0.0` changes quite frequently, so I want to release `com.example:bar:2.1.0`. But I will be building from the aggregate parent POM in that repository, `com.example:foo:1.0.0`. Must I increment the version of the parent POM as well, even though the parent POM has not changed, and even though the versions are not tied to each other in any way? I would prefer to have the `nexus-staging-maven-plugin` simply realize that `com.example:foo:1.0.0` has already been published, skip it, and continue and publish `com.example:bar:2.1.0`.

This question also extends to a sibling module that has already been published. Is there some way to configure `nexus-staging-maven-plugin` to skip a module that has already been published, yet continue building and publishing the other sibling projects that have not been published yet?

From this simplified example I'm sure someone will be tempted to answer, "but you shouldn't do it like that". In my more complex example, there are reasons it might be advantageous to do it like I'm explaining; and besides, that response would still leave the actual question unanswered.

I also realize that I could do some tests to see what happens, and perhaps I will, but I'm posting the question here to 1) get an authoritative answer, 2) promote discussion of the options, and 3) leave some definitive answer here for other who might have the same question.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, the `nexus-staging-maven-plugin` does not have a user property to detach or ignore certain artifacts.

You may be able to write your own plugin that takes the Maven project and eliminates a certain artifact from it.